# Is there a way to compare characters in a string via. python?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am wondering if there is a way that I can compare the first letter of the string to the second; then the third to the forth ... etc.
At the moment I have this:

```
a=0
b=0
string = "GG EZ"
if string[a:b] == string[a+1:b+1]:
    print("hello")
```

It works but is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: `string[a] == string[a+1]` is shorter

Comment: Is your example all that you will be doing? Will you be comparing more than single letter substrings?

Comment: What i want to do is compare each character to the next in a loop until there isn't any characters left. In this example, I would want to print hello each time they match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to pair up the elements

```
s = "GGEZ"
for a, b in zip(*[iter(s)]*2):
    if a==b:
        print('Hello')
```

More on this usage of `zip` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: That is why I love programming. You ask five people about a problem and get five different ideas how to solve it! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "GG EZ abbdff"

for i in range(0, len(string), 2):
    if string[i] == string[i+1]:
        print("characters match")
```

Create a range of every second character in the string. Iterate over the range and compare character at the index `i` with the following.

Edit: If your string length is an odd number you run into an out of range exception. I let you figure that one out by yourself :)